# Get last section from echo and store in variable PHP

Tags: php, function

I've a function that will echo the URL of the image from the content of Wordpress.

I got the function work now no problem

```
// Get Image Attachments
function sa_get_image($postid=0, $size='thumbnail') { //it can be thumbnail or full
    if ($postid<1)
    $postid = get_the_ID();
    $thumb = get_post_meta($postid, "thumb", TRUE); // Declare the custom field for the image
    if ($thumb != null or $thumb != '') {
        echo $thumb;
    }
    elseif ($images = get_children(array( //If you upload an image function gets first image
        'post_parent' => $postid,
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'numberposts' => '5',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image', )))
        foreach($images as $image) {
            $thumbnail=wp_get_attachment_image_src($image->ID, $size);
            ?>
    <?php echo $thumbnail[0]; ?>
    <?php }
        else { //If you don't upload or declare as thumb custom field func. gets custom (default) image
        echo get_bloginfo ( 'template_directory' ); //same as wp-content/themes/your-theme/
        echo '/images/image-pending.gif'; // Put this image into your themes images folder and set the path here
    }
}
```

The only problem now is that the         `<?php echo $thumbnail[0]; ?>` if there are more than one image it will echo all of them something like this

```
<img src="    http://applesiam.com/wp-content/uploads/2555-05-02_19h14_34-150x150.png        http://applesiam.com/wp-content/uploads/2555-05-02_19h14_11-150x150.png        http://applesiam.com/wp-content/uploads/2555-05-02_19h13_43-150x123.png        http://applesiam.com/wp-content/uploads/2555-05-02_19h13_20-150x150.png        http://applesiam.com/wp-content/uploads/2555-05-02_19h13_17-150x150.png    ">
```

As you can see it just separated by some spaces.

Now I just want to have the last image if there is more than one image in the `$thumbnail`

I'm not really expert with PHP as my semester for PHP course will start next week.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion going to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$imgSrc = end((explode(' ', trim($imgSrc)));
```

Where `$imgSrc` is the value you put into `<img src="!!!==>>here<<==!!!">`.

quickly typed, w/o any warranty. Should leave single URLs intact, and if multiple ones separated by space(s) will take the last.

Comment: I'm still getting the same output :(

Comment: Alright, please share the code where `<img src="    http://applesiam.com/wp-content/uploads/2555-05-02_19h14_34-150x150.png        http://applesiam.com/wp-content/uploads/2555-05-02_19h14_11-150x150.png        http://applesiam.com/wp-content/uploads/2555-05-02_19h13_43-150x123.png        http://applesiam.com/wp-content/uploads/2555-05-02_19h13_20-150x150.png        http://applesiam.com/wp-content/uploads/2555-05-02_19h13_17-150x150.png    ">` is actually generated. It looks like that is not part of your question and/or incomplete.

Comment: Are you talking about this? `<img src="<?php sa_get_image($post->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?>" />`

Comment: @Ali: Exactly. Find out when that is triggered so that multiple space separated are there. Isolate it, apply the fix from my answer and you're done.

Comment: The problem is that the above function is not in the same file or it doesn't matter?

Comment: @Ali: That normally doesn't matter, it's available, that matters, not in which file it is placed (it's normal to not only have one file but multiple ones)

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead.
     echo trim($thumbnail[sizeof($thumbnail)-1]);